# Шантряп. Кто или что это?

Tags: значение-слов

Вроде на слово "шантрапа" похоже,но мало ли.

Comment: Примеры использования есть?!

Comment: @behemothus "Или Пашка-Папа̀н — босяк, ну, этот — шантряп, за стакан водки готов сделать все, что угодно, рубашка по пояс и все мелочи наружу, никуда от него не скроешься, как банный лист".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С учетом приведенного примера использования более вероятным представляется диалектная этимология.
Слово фиксируется рядом источников.

> Шантряп. Оборванец. Архангельск.

https://www.liveinternet.ru/users/2463357/post192179241

> ШантрЯп (сущ., м. р.) - оборванец:  Тотъ ПріежжАтъ, ему и стало
>   обидно, онъ ЗапьЯнствовалъ и всё пропилъ, сталъ ходить ШантрЯпомъ
>   КускИ СбирАть (Шантряпъ. Записана отъ Макарова, Ильи Николаевича, 51
>   г. отъ роду. Въ море не хаживалъ, сказки слышалъ дома отъ стариковъ и
>   на промыслахъ «въ лесе».  Н. Е. Ончуковъ. Северныя сказки. С. 539)

https://www.proza.ru/2010/10/18/512

Конечно, вторичное смешение с "шантрапа" в целом не исключено, тем более, что значения в чем-то близки, но тут выглядит именно диалектным.

Можно еще словарь русских говоров посмотреть, он есть в сети, но его качать замучаешься...